# when i type apm publish minor , why token not appear

Tags: atom-editor

I try to first publish my theme to atom.io.

When I type atm to publish minor, I see this message:

> Before you can publish packages, you'll need an API token.
>
> Visit your account page on Atom.io https://atom.io/account,
> copy the token and paste it below when prompted.
>
> Press [Enter] to open your account page on Atom.io.

Then, the pages shows:

> Token> ***TOKEN***
> Saving token to Keychain

Please tell me how to set up the API token.

Comment: APM and its associated registry was sunset in May.

Comment: Welcome to SO! @nazaseo789 I edited your post for grammar to make it understandable, I hope it still explains what you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy to replicate and to resolve:

1. Type `apm login`
2. Press **Enter** to go the other page (shows error 500 for me)
3. Go to https://atom.io/account via browser.
4. Click on your profile in the upper right.
5. Copy the API token from the page
6. Copy it in your terminal.
7. Hit **Enter**.

You see *Saving token to Keychain done*. All is set.

By the way, did you know [this](https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/)?

> We are archiving Atom and all projects under the Atom organization for an official sunset on December 15, 2022.

Comment: Dear Christian 
when I enter  it appear spwan unknown.
and I know about sunset.

Comment: Permission issue? Have you run the terminal as administrator?

Comment: thank you for answer. today i try run as administrator but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Ever since GitHub announced it is [sunsetting Atom](https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/), publishing new or updated packages has rarely been working. As of December 2022, packages can no longer be published, updated, or even installed using the Atom Package Manager. The website for Atom and packages has been taken offline.

With two community-driven forks in the making, [Pulsar Editor](https://github.com/pulsar-edit/) and [Atom Community](https://github.com/atom-community), there is some hope that you can continue to publish your packages in the future.